# How to specify font-size for all bold text in the div?

Tags: html, css

I have the div, containig some html-formatted text like `normal, <b>bold</b>, <i>italic</i>`. 
And I need to change font-size for all bold text only in that div.

So the question is how to do this in html/css, or maybe js?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
div.foo b, div.foo strong {
  font-size: 1.2em
}
```

if you are using inline style like `<i style="font-weight:bold">` case is more complicated.

Then you have to use jQuery+CSS

```
$('div.foo *[style=font-weight:bold]').addClass('myFontSize');

div.foo .myFontSize {
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

But please mind it's not good practice.

Comment: This is probably what was requested for, but technically it does not necessarily set the size of all bold text. The element might contain e.g. a `span` element for which `font-weight: bold` is set.

Answer (score 2):

```
div#divid b { font-size: 18px; }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use element selector as :

```
#divId b
{
font-size:1.1em;
//what ever you want also  
}
```